# Selecting value based on string in attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working with the following bit of html and am trying to select it's value in either plain javascript or jquery. The name attribute can vary so I can't use it as my selector, although it will always represent the same data (grade_level).  I *think* my best way of selecting it is via the string 'students.grade_level, but I'm not sure how to access it.

```
<input type="hidden" name="UF-001008-1$formatnumeric=#########.#####" value="1" data-validation="{"maxlength":"10","isinteger":"true","type":"number","key":"students.grade_level"}">
```

I have so far not been able to select element's value.  I have tried:

```
var myvar = $( "input[data-validation~='students.grade_level']" ).val();
var myvar = $( "input:contains('students.grade_level')" ).val();
```

How else can I go about this?

TYIA

Answer (score 3):

The way that you have given your attribute is wrong,

```
<input type="hidden" name="UF-001008-1$formatnumeric=#########.#####" value="1" data-validation="{'maxlength':'10','isinteger':'true','type':'number','key':'students.grade_level'}">
```

Use quotes properly to cover your attributes, either `escape` the `double quote` or use `single quotes` instead.

And after correcting that you could use the `*=` attibute value contains selector to achieve what you want,

```
var myvar = $( "input[data-validation*='students.grade_level']" ).val();
```

`:contains()` selector will not work out since it would search for matching text content. Also `~=` attribute contains word selector wont work out as we do not have any word in our `data-validation` attribute. Word in the sense, group of texts separated by a space.

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3mwp0tbp/)

Comment: It may be technically incorrect, but that is a straight copy/paste from view->source.  It is the code generated by the product I'm working in.  :(

Comment: @BrianBrock Glad to help! :)